# How to rewrite part of a URL?

Tags: javascript, window.open

I'm using lightbox2 on my site and I want my viewers to download the image. The button works, it links to /view/directory/image.jpg and the download button shows just the image. In PHP I made a scripts that downloads the image and sets download+1 in mysql, the only thing i'm not so good at is JS.

Current JS code in lightbox2 is :

```
this.$lightbox.find('.lb-download').on('click', function (e) {
    window.open(e.target.href)
  });
```

Which links to */view/directory/image.jpg* because of the href whitch shows the image.
I want the lb-download button to go to */**download**/directory/image.jpg*, I already got the download working, just not the window.open and preg_replace part in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the part in the url with word **view** to **download** like this:

```
this.$lightbox.find(".lb-download").on("click", function (e) {
   window.open(e.target.href.replace("/view/", "/download/"))
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply replace the word `view` with `download` by running the following -

```
var urlToBeOpened = e.target.href.replace('view', 'download');
window.open(urlToBeOpened);
```

Comment: much more simple and efficient than my approach.

Comment: Thank you Diego. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
url=e.target.href;
url=url.split("/");
url[0]=url[0]+"/download";
url.join("/");
window.open(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

you got`e.target.href` that contains **"domain.com/view/directory/image.jpg"** and you need it to contain **"domain.com/download/directory/image.jpg"** so you'll have to do:

JS:

```
let dwHref = e.target.href;
dwHref = dwHref.split("/");
dwHref[1] = "download";
dwHref.join("/");
window.open(dwHref);
```

this converts `e.target.href` to an array, then you exchange "view" for "download" (position 1 in the array) and then open the window...

Comment: this gave /album/directory/,download,domain.com,view,directory,image.jpg

Comment: Then I guess `e.target.href` does not contain __"domain.com/view/directory/image.jpg"__ other wise __" /album/directory/"__ wouldn't be there... but well the approach shown by @Simple_Programmer is by far better and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach solving this question is using pattern and replace function

Make a pattern like

```
var pattern = /view/ig;
```

then assume we have a string like

```
var a = "domain.com/view/directory/image.jpg";
```

now simply with replace we can replace any word in that URL

```
a = a.replace( pattern, "download" );
```

here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/mhadaily/0zpekx6t/1/

Note: you can easily change a to e.target.href and apply replace function on that.

Notice: i flag in above pattern means single and g flag makes that global to be applied.

for more infromation please read :https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions